# A question regarding ODEs that must satisfy certain conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

Let us say that I have two quantities: $a$ and $b$, where both are from the set of reals. Always, $a \geq 0$ and $b \geq 0$. In addition, $a + b = C$, where $C$ is a real number such that $C > 0$. $C$ is a constant.

They are related to each other as follows:

$da/dt = -k_{1}(a, b)a + k_{2}(a, b)b$

$db/dt = k_{1}(a, b)a - k_{2}(a, b)b$

As you can see, $k_1$ and $k_2$ are functions that depend on $a$ and $b$, and have the property that they always return a value that is greater than or equal to $0$.

Now, do the conditions I first specified on $a$ and $b$ imply that $k_1(a,b) \leq 1$ and $k_2(a,b) \leq 1$?

Then, would this be a valid way to rewrite the relationships between $a$ and $b$, if I also wanted to incorporate the conditions on them:

$da/dt = -min(k_{1}(a, b)a, a) + min(k_{2}(a, b)(C-a), (C-a))$

$b = C - a$

I have an intuitive feeling regarding this that arises from the situation I am modelling, but no certainty of correctness. Thus, I would appreciate some help in analyzing this problem formally.

Comment: As to your first question, I see no reason to restrict $k_1, k_2 \in [0, 1]$.

Comment: @Macavity I edited the question slightly to include a condition I had forgotten about (namely, that $k_1, k_2 \geq 0$. Also, could you provide more detail regarding why you have this feeling?

Comment: For e.g., solve the system with $k_1=5, k_2=4, a(0)=2, b(0)=2$, you will get well behaved solutions satisfying your initial conditions.

Comment: @Macavity You're totally right. And I guess, there is no reason to expect anything different for $k_1, k_2$ being functions instead of constants. Hmm.